# How can i get the maximum count of an input and values from another column corresponding to that

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns :

```
+-------+--------+
|   A   |     B  |
+=======+========+   
| 123   |   111  | 
| 234   |   222  |
| 345   |   111  |
| 456   |   111  |
| 567   |   222  | 
| 678   |   111  |
+-------+--------+
```

A=Column A is primary key , i have to pass the input 111,222 and query should find out which one of these is occuring most in column b

for eg in table 111 is occuring 4 times so i need values from table A for each occurance  of 111

Comment: I can't see what the problem is. Use a first query to determine the most common value, and a second query to get the IDs. What is your problem?

Comment: input values are both 111 and 222 
sql should decide first which one is occuring most and then according to results it should pick the values from column A

Comment: problem is i am new to sql ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter all are integer types in this case desired result should be 123,345,456,678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Query**

```
SELECT `B` as popular 
FROM your_table 
WHERE `B` IN ('111','222') 
GROUP BY `B` 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 1;
SELECT `A` FROM your_table WHERE B = PUTHEREPOPULAR;
```

Comment: You don't need two queries.

Comment: seems simple and good , but i am using DB2 , limit func is not working here , i suppose it is to get the first value out of all which is with greater occurance right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get count using group by on column b and then select the max count using order by desc on the count and selecting top 1 row only. like below

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT COUNT(1) CountB,B FROM TABLE3 
WHERE B IN (111,222)
GROUP BY B )
SELECT TOP 1 CountB AS MaxCount,B FROM CTE  ORDER BY CountB DESC
```

I have used COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION here.